# Persistence file from Ear across application

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, ear

I have searched this and found a number of answers but I still cannot get it to work. I have an application I am working on from Eclipse. I am using:

Eclipse Kepler, Glassfish 4, Mysql 5.5.31 & EclipseLink

I have an application defined as

```
Ear project

EJB project
   |
    - META-INF
         |
          - persistence.xml

web project
   |
    - servlets etc
```

My persistence.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mazeEJB">
        <jta-data-source>MazeDbRes</jta-data-source>
        <class>mazeJPA.User</class>
        <class>mazeJPA.Agegroup</class>
        <class>mazeJPA.Gender</class>
        <class>mazeJPA.Maze</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

A servlet where I am trying to access a EntityManager:

```
@WebServlet("/User/*")
public class User extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    /*@PersistenceUnit(unitName="mazeEJB")
    private EntityManagerFactory em;*/

    @EJB
    private Users users;
....
```

I currently have the persistenceunit bit commented but if I uncomment that I get an error

```
Cannot Deploy mazeApp
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-unit-ref-name [servlets.User/em] in scope of the module called [mazeApp#mazeWeb.war]. Please verify your application.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

when I try to "Run on Server" for the app. A lot of the answers I have found on this state that I should either place the persistence file in a jar file in the ear or in the lib/META-INF of the ear. I have tried this and a few other combinations but even though it will then deploy I get exceptions when calling the pages involved.

What I find a bit odd is that I do have access to the Users bean. I would like to fix this but I have also contemplated creating a bean for the table I want to access and inject that. Theoretically this should work as I only want to call the default findAll named query generated with my entity.

Also I have tried to look at the ear file generated to see its structure but I don't think Eclipse is packaging it up and deploying as I expect as I can find the directory structure incompressed. Is this part of the issue.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and why I can't get this to work? Even more helpful if someone can explain the Eclipse steps to fix this.

My web project has the EJB project on its build path if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have realised that it was a buildpath issue after all. I had the project on the buildpath for the web project but I needed to add the persistence.xml file itslef to the build path. I had to right-click on the persistence.xml file and select add to build path. This created a persistence.jar file at the root of my ejb project and I can now deploy to the server with no errors.

Comment: Actually that buildpath still caused me problems so I have used beans instead.